# connect mule and facebook tutorial

Tags: facebook, mule

anybody knows a good tutorial on connect `Facebook` and [mule](http://www.mulesoft.com/)

i just started learning `Mule` today and i found a punch of very good tutorial on how to integrate mule with `twitter` and it worked fine, but i couldn't find anything related to `Facebook` connection.

when i search the `youtube`for tutorial almost everything is there (dropbox, salesforce, Linkedin ....)

am i missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Twitter and Facebook connector are extremely similar (they both require an OAuth dance, not the same version but similar), so if you are able to use the Twitter one, you should have no problem using the Facebook one.

To help you going further, here are two good resources:

- A tutorial: https://github.com/mulesoft/facebook-connector/blob/master/doc/sample.md
- The connector's doc: http://mulesoft.github.io/facebook-connector/mule/facebook-config-with-oauth.html